# Apache commons CLI - repeated options

Tags: java, arguments, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I've looked around a bit, and this may be just a case of incorrect terminology but is it possible for Apache commons CLI to handle repeated options? eg:

`program --arg value1 --arg value2 ...`

I know that you can specify multiple option arguments so it will accept stuff like...

`program --arg value1 value2`

... but I'd like to handle an arbitrary number of repeated options. Does anyone know if/how this is possible?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114827/repeated-option-groups-with-commons-cli) question which is somewhat similar, but it was never answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
String[] args = { "-arg", "value1", "-arg", "value2" };
CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption("arg", true, "Argument");
CommandLine line = parser.parse( options, args );

String values[] = line.getOptionValues("arg");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(values));
```

Result:

```
[value1, value2]
```